# Selectedchoice(selected_value) example

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

In SYMFONY 3;

I am building a form in which a bunch of sub form elements depend on a selection made by the user.

So in my TYPE class to define the form, I have :

```
class MyFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('customType', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'label'=>'custom type',
            'choices' => array(
                'choice 1' => 'choice 1',
                'choice 2' => 'choice 2',
            ),
            'multiple' => false,
        ));

        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

In the doc it says [there](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#field-variables) that:

> It's significantly faster to use the selectedchoice(selected_value)
>   test instead when using Twig.

I looked at `selectedchoice(selected_value)`. The idea is  to change the sub-fields that are embedded in the form depending the selection made by the user without sending a new request to the server.

[It describes the use of `selectedchoice(selected_value)` as this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#selectedchoice-selected-value):

> This test will check if the current choice is equal to the
>   selected_value or if the current choice is in the array (when
>   selected_value is an array). 
>   `1 <option {% if choice is selectedchoice(value) %} selected="selected"{% endif %} ...>`

I don't understand how to apply this example in the case that I have in my TWIG file that renders the view:

```
{{ form_row(MyFormType.customType) }}
```

How can I get the choices implied by `{{ form_row(MyFormType.customType) }}` and use  it with that:

```
<option {% if choice is selectedchoice(value) %} selected="selected"{% endif %} ...>
```

Comment: What is the actual problem you try to solve? Is it the pre-selection of a value in a sub-form (how does this sub-type look like then?) or is it really the rendering of the template (if so what are you trying to customise there?)?

Comment: It is the rendering of the template. I need to do something on client side with JS: `<select>` an `<option>` and then the rendering is updated with no reloading (not the Symfony controller rendering, just the rendering as the user sees it if I may speak). I think I was confused by the `selectedchoice` functionnality when I read about it in the doc because it misses an example to understand how one could use it with the `ChoiceType::class` .

Answer (score 0):

try to set value in controller, and it will be rendered as selected choice.